# Shortcut for drag-and-drop + replace file?

Tags: macos, finder

Long-shot question. I have a workflow where I download a file; move it to a location and rename it; perform operations on it; realize I screwed up in the previous step; and have to re-download, move and rename. I often have to do these last two steps several times, because I'm bad at stuff. (This is all done in Finder)

I would love to have some sort of magic keyboard combo where if I hold down these keys while dragging the re-downloaded file from Downloads into the destination AND holding the new file over the old version, it would automatically replace it. Is there some existing way to do this? Or, alternatively, is there a utility out there that I can use to set this up?

Comment: Why not just duplicate the file at each step [option-drag, Cmd/d or  cmd/c, cmd/v] - that would save you a whole lot of repetition.

Comment: Yes, just copy and Paste the file from Downloads to the new location; then you have a 'backup' copy if things go wrong.